# Django + AngularJS - first attempt - variable not evaluated

Tags: django, angularjs, angularjs-directive, django-admin, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to integrate AngularJs with an existing Django application. this is my first attempt with Angular.

Here is the code:

```
<!-- HTML (section)-->

<fieldset class="module aligned">
    <h2>Document's sections</h2>

    <div class="form-row document-nodes" ng-app="DocumentNodesApp">
        <div style="width: 100%; min-height: 450px;" ng-controller="NodeController">
            <form id="changelist-form" action="" method="post" novalidate>{% csrf_token %}
                <div id="tree"
                     data-url="{{ tree_json_url }}"
                     data-save_state="{{ app_label }}_documentnode"
                     data-auto_open="{{ tree_auto_open }}"
                     data-autoescape="{{ autoescape }}"
                >
                </div>
            </form>
            <div id="node-container">
                {$node_title$}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>



// javascript
var app = angular.module('DocumentNodesApp', []);

app.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{$');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('$}');
});

var nodeController = app.controller(
        'NodeController',
        function($scope){
            $scope.node_name = "Bla Bla bla!";
        });
```

What I'm doing wrong?

the variable `node_title` is not replaced with the value assigned. I've also tried to use the normal angular templating filters `{{ }}`, by sorrounding the angular variable with the  django template filter `verbatim`, but I had the same result.

Anybody has experienced the same problems and can help me?

thanks
LuKe

Comment: You haven't assigned a variable named 'node_title' - you've assigned a variable named 'node_name'...

Comment: No worries - I've added my comment as an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

The variable assigned to your `$scope` isn't named 'node_title' - it's named 'node_name'.